# Saving data from hasMany and belongsTo

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I am currently having some trouble with cakephp.
I already try to find an answer on this forum, but nothing really usefull in my case :(
Here is my problem :

I have 2 table :

```
Author  | Role
id      | id
role_id | name
```

I set my Author "belongsTo Role" and my Role "HasMany Author"

On my view, my form looks like this :

```
$this->Form->create('Role')
$this->Form->input('name'));
$this->Form->input('Author.id', array('type' => 'select', 'multiple' => true, 'options' => $authors));
```

My Role controller :

```
function index() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Role->saveAll($this->data)) {
        }
    }
    $this->set('authors', $this->Role->Author->find('list'));
}
```

But when I try to save, my new Role in well created, but it also create a new author row instead of update the existing one.
All i want, is to update the role_id from the Author table when i create a new Role.
Any idea what's wrong ?

Edit: I also get the same result with
    $this->request->data
Instead of 
    $this->data
My data looks like this when I create a new Role assigned with 2 Authors:

```
array(
    'Role' => array(
        'name' => 'test',
    ),
    'Author' => array(
        'id' => array(
            (int) 0 => '1',
            (int) 1 => '3'
        )
    )
)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? From the look of your code it is CakePHP 1.x?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja, Nop, version 2.2.3

Comment: You shouldn't be using `$this->data` within a controller in CakePHP 2.x (that's how it was done in CakePHP 1.x), instead use `$this->request->data`. What does `$this->request->data` look like after you post your form data? Could you update your question with this?

Comment: Just edited it, but no change with request->data :(

Comment: are you sure the data you posted is what you got from the view form ? because your data isn't formatted correctly for hasmany saving. from the docs , it says the hasmany associated model must have its data in numerically indexed array witout the model key

Answer (score 0):

To start with your save data is not in the correct format. You can't set the `Author.id` to be an array, it is expecting an integer so therefore isn't updating your existing data.

Not 100% sure that this will work but try rewriting the save data like this:-

```
$authorIds = Hash::extract($this->request->data, 'Author.id.{n}');

foreach ($authorIds as $authorId) {
    $authors[] = [
        'id' => $authorId
    ];
}

$data = [
    'Role' => $this->request->data['Role'],
    'Author' => $authors
];
```

Then use `$this->Role->saveAll($data)`. (I'm sure there's a more elegant way of writing this, just some quick example code).

Comment: Well, it's not really working fine, because if I update Role, and delete all the author, it will not update Author table automatically :/ There is no way to use a CakePHP function or something ?

Comment: Why would you be deleting all the authors?

Comment: By deleting, I wanted to say "unlink" all the author associated with the Role. Technically, the role_id in the Author table should be automatically set to 0

Comment: @NH3 not sure I follow what you're wanting. Are you saying that if you change Role then any authors currently associated to it will be dissociated and the authors passed in the form submission associated? E.g. for a specific role if before save you have authors A, B and C but after changing the role you want B and C so that A no longer has a role.

Comment: Yes, that's it, my Role have Author A,B,C, and I would like that when I edit the Role with only Author A and C, the Author B will be unlink to the Role (role_id = 0)